# Where should i declare the field in this code in order for it to compile?

Tags: java, variables, declaration

This is not supposed to be a client class. I'm just making a class for others to use. I'm using this for a `Highschool`. For example i have classes for the `address`, `teacher`, `students`, `principal`, `roomnumber`, etc..But its not compiling for some odd reason. I believe its because I'm not declaring a field but not sure.

```
import java.io.*;


public class HighSchool {
    // Constructors
        public HighSchool() { } 

        public HighSchool(String title, String teacher, int roomNumber, String period, String[] students, String address, String subjects ) {
            this.title = title;
            this.teacher = teacher;
            this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
            this.period = period;
            this.String[] students = students;
            this.String address =a ddress;
            this.String subjects = subjects;
        }
        public class Classcourse (String title, String teacher, int roomNumber, String period, String[] students, String  address, String subjects

        private String period;) {

        public String gettitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public void settitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
        public String getteacher() {
            return teacher;
        }
        public void setteacher(String teacher) {
            this.teacher = teacher;
        }
        public int getroomNumber() {
            return roomNumber;
        }
        public void setroomNumber (int roomNumber) {
            this.roomNumber = roomNumber;
        }
        public String getperiod() {
            return getperiod();
        }
        public void setperiod (String period) {
            this.period = period;
        }
        public String[] getstudents () {
            return students[];
        }
        public void setstudents[] (String[] students

        private String address;) {
            this.students = students;
        }
        public String getaddress() {
            return address;
        }
        public void setaddress (String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }
        public String getsubjects() {
            return subjects;
        }
        public void setsubjects (String subjects) {
            this.subjects = subjects;
        }
        }


        // modifier method
        public void addstudents(String students) {
            String[] newstudents = new String[students.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
                newstudents[i] = students[i];
            }
            newstudents[students.length] = student;
            students = newstudents;
        }

        public boolean isInClass(String students) {
            for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
                if (students[i].equals(students)) {
                    return true;
              }
            }


            return false;
        }

        // static creator method
        public static HighSchool readFromInput() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader kb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Enter a HighSchool title: ");
            HighSchool newHighSchool = new HighSchool(kb.readLine());
            String students = null;
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter a student, or press Enter to finish: ");
                students = kb.readLine();
                if (students != null){
                    newHighSchool.addstudents(students);
                }
            } while (students != null);
            return newHighSchool;
        }


        // Variables (Fields)
        private String title;
        private String[] students;
}
```

Comment: What error message is the compiler giving you?

Comment: _Here is a hint_: you should declare the field that the compiler says it **can't** find. The compiler will tell you exactly which one it failed to find! This line looks strange with a white space between letters `a` and `d`: `this.String address =a ddress;` Remove the _white space_.

Comment: _Always_ include your compiler error messages. It is kind enough to tell you exactly what it doesn't like about your input. You'll eventually learn how to understand what compilers are trying to tell you. The process will go much faster if you include error messages, then _we_ can tell you in plain English (or near enough to plain...) what the real problem is. Then you learn. :)

Comment: Gnat it doesnt even give me a compiler message. It doesn't run.

Comment: There are syntax errors as others have pointed out so it couldn't have compiled. What are you using that doesn't give compiler error messages? Can you change to use something that does? Otherwise you'll spend 90% of your time trying to locate errors.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you wrote something that doesn't make sense from the point of view of Java Compiler:

`private String period;) {`
 - probably remove ")".

The second thing:

Take a look on the declaration of class Classcourse.
It rather sounds wrong, although it can be an issue of this site's editor or something...

An "overall" hint - java has a very "intelligent" compiler in the most of the cases it can say what's wrong exactly with your code, so, assuming you're a newbie in Java, try to understand what compiler says to you.

Good luck!

Comment: `;)` That's classic - someone's too used to typing emoticons!

Answer (score 0):

Some things I noticed about the code:

```
    public String getperiod() {
        return getperiod();
    }
```

This code will cause a endless loop when you call this function.

```
    private String address;) {
        this.students = students;
    }
```

The compiler will give an error about the ";)". Change it to "()" to fix this.

Furthermore, you should really tell us more about the errors it's giving you. We can't help you if you don't give us the compiler errors.